# How i can merge List Data from two XML files?

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

File1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>

<wordlist>
        <title>English</title>
        <writer>BASHKIM</writer>
        <word>Father</word> 
        <word>Mother</word>
        <word>Son</word>
</wordlist>
```

File2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<wordlist>
        <title>Spanish</title>
        <writer>BASHKIM</writer>
        <word>Fakhts</word> 
        <word>Moghday</word>
        <word>Sonay</word>
</wordlist>
```

I have two XML files (code posted above), and I want to combine their contents. How can I create output that contains `//worldlist/word` from both files?

I want output like this:

```
For example:
Father-Fakhts
Mother-Moghday
Son-Sonay
```

Comment: What tool/language do you have at your disposal to load and process the files?

Comment: i have loaded both lists in third xml by using XSL.i just want to merge both list as i mentioned output in question.i am writing XSL code in notepad++ and testing in browser.

Comment: **1.** Please show your required output **as code**. -- **2.** Is there anything that links the words in the two lists, other than their position?

Comment: "*i just want to merge both values by traversing.*" I am afraid that doesn't mean much to me. Why don't you answer the questions?

Comment: @ialarmedalien Please restrain yourself: "merge lists from two files" does NOT necessarily mean "create a file".

Comment: @michael.hor257k edited to be more restrained but feel free to redo it yourself.

Comment: i get list from both files in seperate variables.  <xsl:variable name="doc1" select="document('File1.xml')//wordlist/word" />
  <xsl:variable name="doc2" select="document('File2.xml')//wordlist/word" />

Comment: @ialarmedalien I have better things to do.

Comment: @Muhammad I have better things to do.

Comment: Thanks @ialarmedalien for question editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSLT 1.0, if you have the two lists in variables $v1 and $v2, you can do

```
<xsl:for-each select="$v1">
  <xsl:variable name="this" select="."/>
  <xsl:variable name="p" select="position()"/>
  <xsl:variable name="that" select="$v2[$p]"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="concat($this, '-', $that, '&#xa;')"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: can you please do me a bit more favour?i want to sort $v1 and pick value from $v2. how i can do that?

Comment: Please don't make comments on answers that completely change the nature of the original question. Post a new question with the new problem.

Answer (score 2):

In XPath 3.0 you can do

```
for-each-pair(doc('file1.xml')//word, doc('file2.xml')//word, 
              concat(?, ' ', ?, '&#xa;'))
```

You can use that from any XQuery 3.0 or XSLT 3.0 processor.

Comment: LOL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26577584/how-i-can-merge-two-xml-files#comment41772723_26577584

Comment: Now retagged as xslt-1.0. Good to learn something new about XSLT 3.0 once in a while, though!

Comment: how i can merge List from both files? i have fetch list in variables from both files.